# Javascript conditional Timer logic

Tags: javascript

I'm having some problems with a javascript timer logic.

I need to change the opacity of the timer when a number reaches `0`, as well as change the color to red when all the times except the day's property is `0` as well.

I have no problem with the CSS, I'm having a problem with the javascript logic of the timer. I don't know how to write the conditionals. Maybe wrapping all the logic in a function that will be called is a good idea or using s switch statement. Any help is appreciated.

Currently, there is a moment.js function, it is called every second, then it updates a duration object to display the remaining time.

The duration object is as follows:

```
let duration = {
   days: "0",
   hours: 22,
   minutes: 24,
   seconds: 54
}
```

`I also noticed the days property usually return the number as a string`

my conditional looks like this so far:

```
switch (duration) {
  case duration.days === 0 && duration.hours === 0 && duration.minutes 
=== 0 && duration.seconds === 0:
// change all opacities
    break;
  case duration.days === 0 && duration.hours === 0 && duration.minutes === 0:
// change days, hours and minute opacities
    break;
  case duration.days === 0 && duration.hours === 0
  default:
// change days and hours opacities
}
```

The issue:

1. can't switch the opacity of property if the properties that come before them are not zeroed out.
   example minutes or seconds will reach 0 multiple times before hours. but their opacity shouldn't be switched until days and hours are zeroed out
2. changing all the opacity colors to red only when the day's property is zeroed out

[image]

Comment: Have some courage and give it a try, then we can help you fix the problems.  Don't forget you have the && operator.

Comment: How would days be less than zero? Could you not check `if (parseInt(duration.days, 10) === 0)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use some if statements and make it look like:

```
 if (duration.days === 0 && duration.hours === 0 && duration.minutes 
=== 0 && duration.seconds === 0) {
// change all opacities
}
else if (duration.days === 0 && duration.hours === 0 && duration.minutes === 0)     
{
// change days, hours and minute opacities
}
else if (duration.days === 0 && duration.hours === 0) {
// change days and hours opacities
}
else if (duration.days === 0){
//change days opacities
}
```

That should solve the first issue. In regards to the second issue I'd want to have more information about what framework you are using, vanilla js, jquery, react, angular or vue.

Comment: I am using backbone and marionette, but this part of the code is written in vanilla.js and selecting the class to change the opacity is written in jquery

Comment: okay sounds good, I would use the if statement chain above and see if you could change the opacities and the text color inside the if chain as well. I'll see if I can get a working jfiddle going in vanilla.js/jquery, but it'll be tomorrow before I can give it a go.